# Mysql Server 5.6 Mysqld high memory consumption

Tags: windows, memory, configuration, mysql-5.6

I have MySQL Server 5.6 installed in a development machine with these specs:

RAM: 4 GB
Windows 7 Professional 64 bits
Intel Pentium CPU G630 @ 2.70 GHZ

Since I installed the MySQL Server, the process mysqld.exe is consumpting 433 MB.

**What I want to achieve is to reduce this consumption as much as possible**.

**What I have tried**

I read some posts about adding some parameters to the my.ini, but inside the MySQL directory I have a file called my-default.ini so I added the following properties inside:

```
[mysqld]

# join_buffer_size = 128M
# sort_buffer_size = 2M
# read_rnd_buffer_size = 2M 
innodb_buffer_pool_size=5M
innodb_log_buffer_size=256K
query_cache_size=0
max_connections=10
key_buffer_size=8
thread_cache_size=0
host_cache_size=0
innodb_ft_cache_size=1600000
innodb_ft_total_cache_size=32000000

# per thread or per operation settings
thread_stack=131072
sort_buffer_size=32K
read_buffer_size=8200
read_rnd_buffer_size=8200
max_heap_table_size=16K
tmp_table_size=1K
bulk_insert_buffer_size=0
join_buffer_size=128
net_buffer_length=1K
innodb_sort_buffer_size=64K

#settings that relate to the binary log (if enabled)
binlog_cache_size=4K
binlog_stmt_cache_size=4K
performance_schema = off
```

Also I ran these commands to flush the queries cache:

```
FLUSH QUERY CACHE;
RESET QUERY CACHE;
```

All these attempts have not reduced an Megabyte, it stills consumption 433 MB.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check this page about your config files and their location: [Using Option Files](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/option-files.html)

Answer (score 1):

Which version are you using? 5.6.?

I did however came across this bug, hopefully it helps.

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=68287

Comment: Following the comments from your link, I updated to the most recent MySQL Server version 5.6.21 and the memory remains in 433 MB. Do you think is a unsolved bug?

Comment: There are a lot of variables to take into consideration for optimization. Here is a suggestion, open an account on AWS and set up a couple of EC2-Instances to test your theory OR set up an RDS based on your needs.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with my MySql 5.6.10 version, and the following helped me.

Try adding the following in your my.ini (or my.cnf) file under the **`[mysqld]`** part:

```
table_definition_cache = 400
performance_schema=0
```

and restart your mysql server. In my case after doing the above my mysql server's RAM usage went down from ~430MB to ~20 MB.

You can read more about the issue in detail [here](http://www.chriscalender.com/troubleshooting-high-memory-usage-with-mysql-on-windows/).

I hope this helps someone.